# Java Swift BICDownload exitcode=0

Tags: java, swift-mt

I'm automating the download of BIC file, using the [Swift Automation Interface Spec](http://www.swift.com/solutions/messaging/information_products/image_doc/BIC_DA_int_spec_apr09.pdf)

The all ok scenario works ok, but in a simple error scenarios testing with invalid credentials the code in the java sample client application returns a exitcode of 0.

What is wrong with this code?

> /*  * Created on Mar 2, 2007  *
>   S.W.I.F.T. s.c.r.l.  */
>
> public class BICDownloader {
>        public static void main(String[] args) {
>        ...
>        try {
>        ...
>         // Executing the method.
>         statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
>
> ```
>   if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
>    // Handling HTTP error 404 and 500 not covered in this example
>    // All http error cause in this example exit with status 1.
>    System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine()+
>    "\n" + method.getResponseBodyAsString());
>    System.out.println(method.getRequestCharSet()+
>   "\n" + method.getRequestHeader("").toString());
>    exitcode = 1; 
>   }
>   else {
>  ...
>   }      
>  } catch (HttpException e) {
>   exitcode = 2;
>   System.err.println("Fatal HTTP Error: " + e.getMessage());
>   e.printStackTrace();
>  } catch (IOException e) {
>   exitcode = 3;
>   System.err.println("Fatal I/O error: " + e.getMessage());
>   e.printStackTrace();
>  } finally {
>   // Release the connection.
>   method.releaseConnection();
>   System.exit(exitcode);
>  } 
>  System.out.println("Dowload done");
> ```
>
> } 
>   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by a hidden NullPointerException, the cause of problem is in the block of code

```
        System.out.println(method.getRequestCharSet()+
        "\n" + method.getRequestHeader("").toString());
        exitcode = 1;
```

The solution I chosen is changing the instruction method.getRequestHeader("").toString() to Arrays.toString(method.getRequestHeaders()) and adding the clause } catch (Exception e) just in case.